# black pants (jeans?) with silver/gray pockets and gold dot

Tags: part-identification

Do you recognize these pants? Are they on Bricklink, etc.? (I looked on Bricklink and Rebrickable but couldn't spot a match.)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is :

Part# 970c00pb176

[Hips and Legs with Gray Jacket Tails Outline and Gold Button Pattern (Lord Vampyre)](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=970c00pb176&in=M)

Keyword: Gold button